# Fast data processing on large python dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, pattern-matching, dataframe, bigdata

I have a huge data frame that contains 4 columns and 9 millions rows. For example my MainDataframe has :

```
NY_resitor1 NY_resitor2    SF_type        SF_resitor2 
     45           36          Resis          40                  
     47           36          curr           34                    
      .            .           .              .                   
     49           39          curr           39 
     45           11          curr           12 
     12           20          Resis          45
```

I would like to have two dataframes and save them as csv file based on the SF_type namely Resis and curr.
This is what i wrote

```
 FullDataframe=pd.read_csv("hdhhdhd.csv")
 resis=pd.DataFrame()
 curr=pd.DataFrame()  

 for i in range(len(FullDataframe["SF_type"].values)):
     if Resis in FullDataframe["SF_type"].values[i]:
          resis.loc[i]=FullDataframe[["NY_resitor1", "NY_resitor2",  "SF_type","SF_resitor2"]].values[i]

     elif curr in  in FullDataframe["SF_type"].values[i]:
          curr.loc[i]=FullDataframe[["NY_resitor1", "NY_resitor2",  "SF_type","SF_resitor2"]].values[i]

 resis.to_csv("jjsjjjsjs.csv")
 curr.to_csv("jjsj554js.csv")
```

This is what i wrote and i have been running it for the past week but it is still not yet complete. Is there a better and faster way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You will have better luck with a pandas filter rather than a for loop.  Just to stick with convention I'm calling your `FullDataFrame` `df` instead:

```
resis = df[df.SF_type == 'Resis']
curr = df[df.SF_type == 'curr']
```

Then run your:

```
resis.to_csv("jjsjjjsjs.csv")
curr.to_csv("jjsj554js.csv")
```

I'm not sure what your index is, but if you are not using just the default pandas index (i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3 etc.), then you will see a performance boost by sorting your index (`.sort_index()` method).

Comment: When I do that, my two frames are empty. My df.SF_type is of type object; so when I use == it returns false

Comment: What if you convert it to `str` for the equality statement? like `resis = df[df.SF_type.astype(str) == 'Resis']`